# creating good database for telegram bot in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

this function allows me to store the variable in a single column, how can I store the next variable in the next column?

The code register the user but don't cross check(user can register multiple  times), how do i make a good database for taking appointments. I do not know where to start, even little help will be appreciated.

Comment: This funtion allow me to store variable in single column. What variable? What column? What next variable and next column?

Comment: the text i get from the user it gets stored in one column and the next text is stored below it. but i want to store the text in a row like we do in php and sql

Comment: what do `db.get_items` and `db.add_item` functions do?

Comment: add_item() takes the text for the item and inserts it into our database table.

get_items() returns a list of all the items in the database from a single (first) column in tuple formate.

Comment: @IvanVinogradov I also have update the question with the code that i tried now(made now)

Comment: @IvanVinogradov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Some observations

So, you get appointments (one by one) from user and store them to table rows.

To store your data in a database you use `add_item()` method:

```py
def add_item(self, item_text, owner):
    stmt = "INSERT INTO items (description, owner) VALUES (?, ?)"
    args = (item_text, owner)
    self.conn.execute(stmt, args)
    self.conn.commit()
```

And the table schema is

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (description text, owner text)
```

And according to row `self.conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)`, you're using an SQLite database.

#### Problem

> this function allow me to store variable in single column, how can i store next variable in next column?
>   ...
>   the text i get from the user it gets stored in one column and the next text is stored below it. but i want to store the text in a row like we do in php and sql

1. You cannot store next appointment in "next column" because SQLite has a schema, i.e. each table has predefined number of columns with or without type and restrictions. Since number of appointments is undefined and you cannot have a table with undefined number of columns.
2. Furthermore, relational databases (SQLite, MySQL, etc.) are not designed to hold schemaless data (like in your case).
3. Each row in SQLite should represent a record / an instance of class / an entity. That's why the new row created each time you call `add_item()`. That's the way it works. So when you want to list all appointments of user, you receive a set of rows, not a single row with N appointments stored in separate columns.

By the way I didn't understand what do you mean by this:

> i want to store the text in a row **like we do in php and sql**

#### What to do next

In my opinion you have following options to choose from:

- Switch to NoSQL databases like MongoDB or Redis for example. Most NoSQL databases have no schema, you can insert data of arbitrary structure in it and you can store a `list` of objects natively. You can use a single JSON document in MongoDB, representing a user and its appointments, or a `list` of appointments for user's chat_id key in Redis.
- If you wish to stay with relational databases, you can switch to database which supports `list` as a column type. SQLite does not support this data type, but [Postgres has](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html). The reason why SQLite does not have this feature is because it's designed to simple and portable (one database = one file, but can also be stored completely in RAM).
- Leave current DB and table schema as it is and store appointments in **rows** because it seems okay for this simple task. Adapt your code for this DB data structure if necessary.

You can ask more questions in comments section if you want.

Comment: while waiting for your reply on this, I tried and make something with pleasing [Please have a look here](https://github.com/aqibfareex/telegram_appointment-/blob/master/tele.py). and I totally get your point, I don't know how to use any other database. if you could help that will be very helpful for me and appreciable.@IvanVinogradov

Comment: why can't you use current database with its schema?

Comment: I am having problem making the logic

Comment: Describe it in more detail

Comment: I want to ask for what service you want the appointment for just the name and then ask for dake from a custom keyboard that keyboard should check if the and hour is already book and the save those details in the DB. Can you guide me on that please @IvanVinogradov